# Update syntax on ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax

How do I update in ruby?

My database is: `Books`
width: `Id, Title and Date`

To create I would do:

```
@book = Book.create   
@book.id = 1 
@book.Title = "HP: Last One"
@book.Date = "2011-01-01"
@book.save
```

Now, if I want to update the Book with Id = 1, what to do?

Comment: Update... a database?  Presumably by using some sort of database adapter, but we can't really help you with that little information.

Comment: You read the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Active Record (for example through **Rails**), provided that you have model `Book` that derives from `ActiveRecord::Base` and that `book` is an instance of it (for example: `book = Book.find(1)` will find you a book with id of 1), it would be something like: `book.update_attributes(:title=>"new title", :date=>new_date)`; or `book.title = "new title"; book.date = new_date; book.save`.

No idea about other object-relational mappings, though.